# Replacing value in set_fact

Tags: ansible

below is my sample yaml file

```
student:
  faculty: "Information Technology"
  code: "FC1412"
  abraham:
    country: "UK"
    age: "56"
  aaron:
    country: "UK"
    age: "56"
  chin:
    country: "UK"
    age: "56"
```

Below is my Ansible code

```
- slurp:
    src: {{ yaml_file_directory }}
  register: registerValue

- debug:
    msg: {{ registerValue['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml }}
```

It wil lgive output as below

```
student: {
  faculty: "Information Technology",
  code: "FC1412",
  abraham: {
    country: "UK",
    age: "56"
  },
  aaron:
    country: "UK",
    age: "56",
  },
  jamess: {
    country: "UK",
    age: "56"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to replace a value like aaron age 56 to 57. I wish your guys advice

Comment: By "*replace a value*" do you mean you want to update the YAML file? Or just set it in the play to use later?

Comment: i would need to update the yaml file. The update yaml file I will use copy module. But before that i need update the value in set_Fact then override the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries are immutable in Ansible. You'll have to overwrite the whole dictionary. For example, put the updates into a dictionary

```yaml
        update:
          aaron:
            age: "57"
```

and use the filter [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries). Set `recusive=True` to keep all attributes

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        student: "{{ student|combine(update, recursive=True) }}"
      vars:
        update:
          aaron:
            age: "57"
```

gives

```yaml
  student:
    aaron:
      age: '57'
      country: UK
    abraham:
      age: '56'
      country: UK
    code: FC1412
    faculty: Information Technology
    jamess:
      age: '56'
      country: UK
```

Comment: is this update same as update_fact? i saw we can do with json_query, u have idea on it?

Comment: The module [*update_fact*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#ansible-utils-update-fact-update-currently-set-facts) does the same as the filter *combine*. It's up to you what 'tool' you use. The decision might depend on the structure of the data you have. *json_query* is also a filter that might serve the purpose. Again, depending on the data you have. Anyway, if you have other issues open a new question and make it [mre].

Comment: thanks you. if you have json query sample lease share. i can do it but not sure how it can repalce

Comment: You're welcome. Neither *json_query* can replace it. Nobody can. It's immutable. You can only overwrite it. *json_query* is good in complex queries.  A lot of [shares](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples). Still the same, open [mre] if you have a case.